# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.cucumber.testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, abstract-class, pom.xml

I am getting "java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.cucumber.testng" When I try to runrunner class in selenium cucumber automation.

[Error log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehd1D.png)

Please find below pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>seleniumMaster</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>16</source>
          <target>16</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]. Instead include your code as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies in your pom are consistent. However you are using Intellij IDEA which does not automatically reload the project after making changes to the pom file.

You may have to reimport tbe project. There should be a button for that in the Maven drawer.